# VLAN "trunking" with 2 ZyXEL GS1920-48HP

Tags: networking, vlan, zyxel

I'm trying to setup two ZyXEL GS1920-48HP swithes in different parts of a building. Each of them have the following VLANS:

1 (Default)
10 (WLAN) - for SonicWALL SonicPoints

I know ZyXEL doesn't have a trunking mode for ports, so I'm trying to configure the switches to wrk in the following configuration:

[Firewall] <-> [ZyXEL 1] <-> [ZyXEL 2]

[ZyXEL 1]
VLAN 1: Default LAN 
VLAN 10: WLAN VLAN

Port 1: Connected to SonicWALL X0 (VLAN 1 - Untagged)
Port 2: Connected to [ZyXEL 2] (VLAN 1 - untagged, VLAN 10 - tagged)
Port 3 - 44: LAN connections (VLAN 1 - Untagged)
Port 45 - 48: Connected t X5 on SonicWALL and SonicPoints (VLAN 10 - Untagged)

[ZyXEL 2]
VLAN 1: Default LAN
VLAN 10: WLAN VLAN
Port 1: Connected to {ZyXEL 1] (VLAN 1 - untagged, VLAN 10 - tagged)
Port 2 - 44: LAN Connections (VLAN 1 - Untagged)
Port 45 - 48: Connected to SonicPoints (VAN 10 - untagged)

My problem:
When connected to [ZyXEL 2], I can communicate on default VLAN, but cannot communicate over VLAN 10. It may work for a few seconds then stop. I think I'm overlooking something simple. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had my tagged/untagged port reversed.